# Redux Toolkit "action.payload" query

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

```js
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // User k set korche
    setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<string | null>) => {
      state.user.email = action.payload;
    },
    setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
      state.isLoading = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

I want to clear the concept of `action.payload`. Why I use it here and what does it do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the Redux-Toolkit (RTK) slice:

> ```
> const userSlice = createSlice({
>   name: 'user',
>   initialState,
>   reducers: {
>     // User k set korche
>     setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<string | null>) => {
>       state.user.email = action.payload;
>     },
>     setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
>       state.isLoading = action.payload;
>     },
>   },
> });
> ```

and assumed exports:

```js
export const { setUser, setLoading } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

This slice generates a few things, but most notably it generates the exports above:

1. Generates `setUser` and `setLoading` action functions based on the reducer functions you have declared.
2. A slice reducer function that is passed to the store, or combined with other reducers to form a reducer tree, when the store object is created. e.g. `configureStore`.

> I want to clear the concept of `action.payload`. Why I use it here and
> what does it do?

All Redux action functions return an action object, e.g. an object with a `type` property. RTK-generated actions return action objects with a `payload` property. This is the `action.payload` you see in the reducer functions.

If for example you dispatch the `setUser` action from the UI.

```js
dispatch(setUser("Drew"));
```

```js
dispatch(setUser(null));
```

This first calls the `setUser` action with the string argument `"Drew"`|`null`, and returns an action object `{ type: "user/setUser", payload: "Drew" }`|`{ type: "user/setUser", payload: null }` that is passed to the `dispatch` function, similar to `dispatch({ type: "user/setUser", payload: "Drew" })`, to be passed to the reducer tree.

The `setReducer` reducer function then handles this `"user/setUser"` action type and accesses the action object's `payload` property.

```js
setUser: (state, action: PayloadAction<string | null>) => {
  state.user.email = action.payload; // "Drew" or null
}
```

The result is that `state.user.email` is set to the payload value `"Drew"` in the store.

Similarly you can dispatch a boolean value with the `setLoading` action.

```js
dispatch(setLoading(true));
```

```js
setLoading: (state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) => {
  state.isLoading = action.payload; // true
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I understand the concept.